# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.LocalHomeProxy (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

The code fragment below works when I the application is deployed in JBOSS as a EJB services.

I get a exception when I call the same code as a standalone program in eclipse. Is it not possible to call this on a simple java project ?

```
AuthenticationServices.getInstance().createSession("abcd");
```

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.LocalHomeProxy (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:845)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.ejb.EjbHomeLoader.getRemoteHome(EjbHomeLoader.java:68)
    at com.ejb.EjbHomeLoader.getRemoteHome(EjbHomeLoader.java:45)
    at com.ejb.EjbManager.getEjbHome(EjbManager.java:238)
    at com.ejb.EjbManager.getEjbObject(EjbManager.java:184)
    at com.services.BaseServices.executeLocalEjbMethod(BaseServices.java:294)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.LocalHomeProxy (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
```

Comment: I have edited your question. I hope its correct.

Answer (score 0):

The class is in JBOSS.jar, please add it in your class path.

Comment: standalone program is running in one network and EJB service is running in one network.even though if you put above jar in classpath then also it wont work